# Filtering object with nested arrays by several values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter object with nested arrays by several criteria. Filtering options are generated dynamically and stored in array. This options values are theme id's in nested objects. If filtering options contain for example 2 id's values I need to show all objects that have that theme id's.

```
let data = {
  '17 may': [
    {
      id: 31,
      name: 'Test Name',
      theme: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Theme Test Name',
      },
    },
  ],
  '18 may': [
    {
      id: 41,
      name: 'Test Name',
      theme: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Theme Test Name',
      },
    },
    {
      id: 43,
      name: 'Test Name',
      theme: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Theme Test Name',
      },
    },
  ],
  '19 may': [
    [
      {
        id: 51,
        name: 'Test Name',
        theme: {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Theme Test Name',
        },
      },
      {
        id: 52,
        name: 'Test Name',
        theme: {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Theme Test Name',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};

filteringOptions = [1,2]; // theme id's
```

I use filtering function for nested objects. It's working fine, but I dont' know how to pass more than one filtering option.

```
filterArray(array, filters) {
    const filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
    return array.filter((item) => {
      return filterKeys.every((key) => {
        if (typeof filters[key] !== 'function') return true;
        return filters[key](item[key]);
      });
    });
  }
```

Filtering algorithm

```
const filteredByThemeId = {};

for (const day in data) {
  filteredByTheme[day] = [];
  this.data[day].map((item, index) => {
    filteredByThemeId[day][index] = [
      ...filterArray(item, {
        theme:
          (theme) => {
            if (!theme) return;
            return theme.id === 2; // works fine, but I need to pass all values from filtering options array (options can contain 2, 5, 10 etc. values)
          },
      }),
    ];
  });
}
```

Comment: Suppose you want to filter for all values in list called filterList = [2,5,10]. Instead of `return theme.id === 2`, you can try `return filterList.includes(theme.id)`

Comment: @ShubhamPeriwal seems to work! thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to filter for all values in list called `filterList = [2,5,10]`. Instead of `return theme.id === 2`, you can try `return filterList.includes(theme.id)`